# R: plotting a barchart of percentages of individuals with two conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I will like to plot the percentage of individuals with conditions A and B, A and C, and A and D in the following dataset:

```
Lines <- "id sex Age A B C D
1       male   90 1 1 0 1
2       female  87 0 1 1 0
3       male  50 1 1 0 0
4       female  54 0 1 0 1"
```

Ideally a barchart with the X-axes B, C, and D and the Y-axes the percentage. Can this be done through a function that can be extrapolated to a setup with many variables and also broken by sex and age > 55?

Comment: This is a bar chart and not a histogram.  A histogram is the bin count of a single independent variable.  This is chart is of the percentage (dependent variable) versus the independent category B, C and D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic solution.
The below solution is using `sapply` to loop across the columns and then ggplot to create the chart.

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="id sex Age A B C D
                1       male   90 1 1 0 1
                2       female  87 0 1 1 0
                3       male  50 1 1 0 0
                4       female  54 0 1 0 1")


#perform the calculations
results<- sapply(5:7, function(colid) {
        cond <- names(df)[colid]
        result <- sum(df[["A"]]& df[[cond]])
})
conditions<-paste0("A", names(df)[5:7])

results <- data.frame(conditions, results)


#plotting
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

g<- ggplot(results, aes(x=conditions, y=results/ncol(df))) +
        geom_col(fill="blue") +
        scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), labels=label_percent())
print(g)
```